Apply Jacobi-Anger expansion and return infinite sum
I have an expression
Sin[z Sin[th]]
I want Mathematica to apply the Jacobi Anger expansion, and it works:
FourierTrigSeries[Sin[z Sin[th]], th, 1]
gives
2 BesselJ[1, z] Sin[th]
However, I would like it give the infinite sum
2 Sum[BesselJ[2n-1,z]Sin[(2n-1)th],{n,1,Infinity}]
How should I convince Mathematica to do so?

Mathematica can't compute the series,
but using a workaround:
"14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"

2 Sum[BesselJ[2 n - 1, z] Sin[(2 n - 1) t], {n, 1, Infinity}](*Can't compute.Gives Input*)

2*InverseLaplaceTransform[Sum[LaplaceTransform[BesselJ[2 n - 1, z] 
Sin[(2 n - 1) th], z, s],{n, 1, Infinity}] // FullSimplify, s, z](*Workaround*)

(* Sin[z Sin[th]] *)

then we have:
$$2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } J_{2 n-1}(z) \sin ((2 n-1) \text{th})=\sin (z \sin (\text{th}))$$
We can check:
f[z_, th_] := 2 NSum[BesselJ[2 n - 1, z] Sin[(2 n - 1) th], {n, 
1, Infinity}]; g[z_, th_] := Sin[z Sin[th] // N]
{f[2, 3], g[2, 3]}

(* {0.278508, 0.278508} *)

EDITED 29.11.2024
Using @azerbajdzan answer and workaround we can find more coefficients up too 22:
A = FourierSinCoefficient[(-1)^m/(1 + 2 m)!*( z Sin[th])^(1 + 2 m) // 
PowerExpand, th, n] // FullSimplify
B = Sum[Table[A, {n, 1, 22}] // FullSimplify, {m, 0, Infinity}]

(*{2 BesselJ[1, z], 0, 2 BesselJ[3, z], 0, 2 BesselJ[5, z], 0, 
2 BesselJ[7, z], 0, 2 BesselJ[9, z], 0, 2 BesselJ[11, z], 0, 
2 BesselJ[13, z], 0, 2 BesselJ[15, z], 0, 2 BesselJ[17, z], 0, 
2 BesselJ[19, z], 0, 2 BesselJ[21, z], 0}*)


Hi, thanks for your answer! This is the inverse, though. In most cases, one wants to go from Sin[z Sin[th]] to the Jacobi Anger expansion with the Bessel functions.

@BoudewijnVerhaar .Your question is how compute with Mathematica the infinty sum. I gave you the answer.

No, you misunderstood. I want it to return the infinite sum
2 Sum[BesselJ[2n-1,z]Sin[(2n-1)th],{n,1,Infinity}]

Thank you @Mariusz Iwaniuk !

FourierTrigSeries (or FourierSinCoefficient can be used in this case for simplicity) returns correct result but for some reason Mathematica is not able to simplify the coefficients.
For example the first four coefficients are returned in proper form but the fifth can be further simplified which Mathematica fails on.
But if we provide it the correct result 2 BesselJ[5, z] then Mathematica is able to verify that the expressions are equivalent - i.e. returns True.
FourierSinCoefficient[Sin[z Sin[th]], th, #] & /@ Range[5]
FullSimplify[Last@%]
FullSimplify[Last@%% == 2 BesselJ[5, z]]


{2 BesselJ[1, z], 0, 2 BesselJ[3, z], 0,
(2 (z (-48 + z^2) BesselJ[1, z] - 12 (-16 + z^2) BesselJ[2, z]))/z^3}

(2 (z (-48 + z^2) BesselJ[1, z] - 12 (-16 + z^2) BesselJ[2, z]))/z^3

True

